# Is there a way to get basic PHP error underlining in VIM?

Tags: php, vim, ide

I really like VIM but one thing I cannot do without is simple error underlying like in netbeans and Visual Studio.
I often make silly mistakes like

```
    if checkit($url) 
    {
    }
```

instead of

```
if (checkit($url))
{
}
```

The little squiggly red underline is a lifesaver when it comes to stuff like that. Is there a plugin for VIM that will save me from php silly mistake hell? Thanks.

Comment: I am sure someone can give you a recommendation. However, what i always do is type out the basic structure of the if/else loop first before inserting other statements. eg `if ( ){  
}else{}` . Then i type in whatever is needed inside the braces. that way i won't miss out any braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736)

To make it work efficiently you can add this one small customization to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! s:SaveAll()
    w | :Error
endfunction
command! -bar -narg=0 W call s:SaveAll()
```

now using `:W` for saving your file will also show a location list with any errors.

Comment: You can also just add
`let g:syntastic_auto_loc_lis=1` to your .vimrc to have syntastic automatically open the location list with the errors for you

You can also put `let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1` in your .vimrc to have vim insert markers in the indentation that shows which lines contain errors.

Comment: @Sam - that's awesome, adding it to my `.vimrc` now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [CheckSyntax plugin for vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1431), which has support for the equivalent of the 'php -l' and 'php -f' checks.

Vim doesn't have support for the squiggly underline we're all so used to but you might be able to get the "red marker in a column" effect used in Eclipse with help from [this blog post](http://viming.blogspot.com/2009/12/entire-file-view-of-matching-searches.html).

Answer (score 1):

Syntastic is my life saver. Check it out http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736